# Using List<Custom_Class> in ListView

Tags: java, android

Ive created a class Contact which contains the general structure of my SQL Db. I wish to recieve my data in the form of a List so I use the following code in my MainActivity

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
// Error in this line
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<List<Contact>>(this, R.layout.activity_main, contacts);

contactList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This gives the error `Cannot resolve constructor`

the getAllContacts() looks like this

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {

    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

So how do I receive my data as List and populate my list?

Comment: use `new ArrayAdapter<Contact>` instead of `new ArrayAdapter<List<Contact>>`

Comment: Call the `ArrayAdapter` constructor like this:
`ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, contacts);`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, java.util.List<T>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template of the ArrayAdapter is the record type, in your case Customer, not List
so correct code will be

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, R.layout.activity_main, contacts);
```